# не получается записать объект в sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, get, angular5, asp.net-core-webapi

Возвращаю так:

```
[HttpGet("api/Account/SignInGoogle/{access_token}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> _signInGoogle(string access_token)
{
 ///... код....
 return Ok(new {
     access_token = GenerateJwtToken(_user.Email, _user).ToString(),
     user_name = _user.UserName,
     user_email = _user.Email
 });
}
```

получаю и вывожу в консоль, а потом пытаюсь записать:

```
this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
  (userData) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("googleToken",userData.token);
    this.authService.login().subscribe(
      res =>{
        console.log(res);
        sessionStorage.setItem("userData", res);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

sessionStorage:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли как то записать распарсенный объект?

Comment: в indexeddb можно без ручной сериализации-десериализации, но это постоянное хранилище, а не сессионное..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sessionStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(res));
...
var res = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("userData"));
```

Comment: Спасибо....меня чет потянуло сразу парсить